# Is this question on-topic? Infinitely fast and strong laser targets the Earth

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

I would like to ask a purely hypothetical question regarding the following:

What if I had an infinitely strong and fast laser that can cut through anything it passes. If it has a fixed diameter (let's say 10 cm) and I pointed it from my location to the center of the earth, what would be the consequences for the planet and for the humans.

Is such question on-topic on this site?

Answer (score 8):

This question is, largely, not on topic. "Infinitely strong" and "infinitely fast" are not real physical descriptors for a laser pulse.

Moreover, to the extent that there's a concrete physical setup at stake, asking "what would be the consequences?" is rather too open-ended for this site.

A question along those lines *might* be on-topic at [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/), but ultimately you have to check with them.